# Order by statement in Microsoft Access with parameter

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have a table in Microsoft Access named `tblPerson` with three column:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Score

How I can create a query that define ordering column with parameter?

Comment: You can't use parameters to define the structure of a query, only values in a query.  To dynamically change the structure (such as ordering by a different column) then you'll need to concatenate string values into the query.  *Be very careful* not to concatenate user-supplied values when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Choose function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-Function-76230415-910f-463a-a799-cf7e90aa7fd4):

```
SELECT tblPerson.Id, tblPerson.Name, tblPerson.Score
FROM tblPerson
ORDER BY 
    Val(Choose([OrderBy],[ID],[Name],[Score])),
    Choose([OrderBy],[ID],[Name],[Score]);
```

where OrderBy is your parameter from 1 to 3.

Note that fields will be sorted first as numerics than as strings.